# Find the largest odd number in a list

Tags: python

```
numbers = [1, 2 ,3, 4, 5]
l = 0
for n in numbers:
    if n%2 != 0 and n > l:     
        #print(n)
        l = n

if l == 0:
    print ('Odd numbers are not inputted')
else:
    print ('Largest odd no. is: ', l)
```

After identifying the integers used if they are odd(which is this case) or even, I ran the program and it did showed that 5 is the largest odd in the list. I was curious as to how did this happen, so I tried printing the variable 'n' which then results in the following numbers: 1, 3, 5.

If l = n which means l is equal to 1, 3 and 5, how come this else statement

```
else:
    print ('Largest odd no. is: ', l)
```

identifies and prints the largest number in the list? I do hope someone could shed some light for me and help me understand this dilemma of mine.

Answer (score 6):

`l` is not "equal to 1, 3, and 5". It is equal to 1 the first time through, then it is subsequently set to 3, then to 5, and then the loop ends. So it retains the value it had when the loop ends, which is 5.

Answer (score 2):

This should make things more obvious:

```
# Integers 1, 2 ,3, 4, 5 are used
l = 0
for n in numbers:
    if n%2 != 0 and n > l:     
        l = n
        print("L is now {}:".format(l))    # <=
    else:
        print("skip {}".format(n))         # <=
```

which results in

```
L is now 1:
skip 2
L is now 3:
skip 4
L is now 5:
```

Comment: Maybe a bit more obvious if you `print` *after* the assignment and actually use `l`!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: (shrug) functionally identical, but eh, why not? Code updated.

Comment: @HughBothwell This is a great help sir ^_^ I'm still a beginner in using python so would you please explain what does .format do?

Comment: @YuYumenoPie: basic string formatting; see the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings